# Issue with URL rewrite when having 2 or more parameters

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, urlrewriter, urlfor

I'm facing an issue with my site where URL rewrite is not working using URLFOR() for 2 or more parameters. As per an answer on Stack Overflow this is an existing issue.

[Site.UrlRewriter Interface implementation problem with more than 2 parameters](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/site-urlrewriter-interface-implementation-problem-with-more-than-2-parameters)

The problem is as per requirement I cannot generate the links having ids on each page  from the controller and I can only use the UrlRewrite functionality.

Has anyone faced this issue and are there any other workarounds for this issue? Please let me know as soon as possible since this is an urgent requirement for the client.

*Creating separate question since the the requirement is slightly different from the previous one. Also I would need workarounds if any. All proper suggestions are welcome and will be upvoted.*

Comment: I think it works when parameters are named alphabethic char + sesuential numeric char, and all parameters are at all times in the url, in the right order. That's what we found to bypass the bug over a year ago. At the time T3 support agreed with our conclusion, never heared if they actually  fixed it.